# How do I correct the user Interface font rendering pixels-per-inch (PPI) setting in Indesign to match my target device?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, epub

I have a document set up for intent "Mobile" with resolution of 1125px 2436px, iPhone X.

I'm using an eBook template I downloaded from Adobe Stock.

At 14 points, the font is rendering to the display like this:

[image]

Obviously this is not going to fly on a device that is 5" wide.  How I set the font to render on screen at the correct resolution for 14 point type?

*I've checked here and the Adobe forums. There are numerous discussion of getting high res PDFs to generate correctly.  On this forum, I've seen discussions of generating JPEGs from Indesign.  However, that's not what I'm trying to do.  I'm just trying to get the Indesign user interface to render what the eBook will look like on the iPhone approximately correctly.  As stated above, it appears that the product is conflating pixels with points; typographical points are 72 per inch and pixels are in the 300-500 per inch range on high res devices such as the iPhone X. Is this conflation something that can be corrected.*

*I bump the font size to 60pt so that Indesign is showing an approximate representation of the output device.   I preview the resulting epub on MacOS, the books app is actually treating the font instruction as 60 pt, and rendering a jumbo font.
[image]*

When rendering on a Kindle Paperwhite, the font size goes back up to 60 pts.

[image]

According to [IPhone X: viewport, screen size, CSS pixel ratio](https://blisk.io/devices/details/iphone-x),

> Viewport or Viewport size is the number of software pixels (CSS pixels) present on a screen. Usually, viewport size displays as viewport width in pixels to viewport height in pixels.

This same source, blisk.io, says the iPhone viewport size is 376px812px.

The document is currently configured in InDesign using the iPhone X artboard size setting.  For more information on Indesign page size options see [mobile template size](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/mobile-template-size/td-p/9863166) in the Adobe community pages.

Comment: By changing the font size to 60 points, I am getting an approximate size match with the font  in the "Notes" application on the iPhone.

Comment: You should probably change your documents size to match the phones physical dimensions instead of worrying about pixels as units

Comment: indesign does not have a ppi setting. Its a page description language, it does not have a resolution. Having a pixel as a unit in a page description is a kludge, it does not make sense for anything other than raster exports as you can do it in 2 ways but still have pixels of different size.

Comment: Are you suggesting define the doc size as if pixels equals points?   So instead of being 1152 px wide it would be 5x72 = 350px wide?  I'll try that...

Comment: no forget pixels make the document the same physical sizeas the phone. The system does not care of pixels

Comment: Okay so you are aware that [Indesign accepts page size settings in pixels](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/mobile-template-size/m-p/9863179#M100042) and you are saying not do to this, to configure device size in inches or some other measure,  that accurately represents the size of the device.

Comment: I am aware that the kludge of having fixed size pixels has been added yes. Its not useful though. Dont use it youll be happier and end up actually undeestanding how things really work.

Comment: I'm no e-book expert (only made around 10), so take this for what it's worth. But as I understand it, getting a proper preview in InDesign is kind of a lost cause. You don't really design *pages* anyway - it's more like a long *scroll* of text. If I were to make an e-book, I would probably ignore the preview altogether. Maybe just apply styles in *Story Editor* and edit the styles without live preview. But then again - I've only made novels. Not many styles to keep track of.

Comment: @Wolff yes its like a webpage as in ot flows the text anyway.

Comment: @Wolff yes that makes sense. I am doing flowable source code listings (pre) so I want some way to verify the font settings are in the ballpark.